# Passing Inner div Text to Function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

My aim is that when the user clicks the row which has a particular data entry, they will be given further information about it. So far my logic was to have the user click the row and there to be a function which passes the innerHTML argument, which is then handled by another function that retrieves additional information. So if there is a list like:

`John Doe`

`Jane Doe`

`Joe Blow`

I thought that when the user was to click on their names, the innerHTML string of whatever they clicked (e.g. "John Doe") would somehow be passed to getInformation(fullName) where fullName would be "John Doe".

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class='row' onclick=alert((this).innerHTML)>
    <div class='label'>
         John Doe
     </div>
</div>
<div class='listSeparator'></div>
```

The problem is I'm not too sure how to implement this. The **(this).innerHTML** above obviously doesn't work since it would just return `"<div id ='labeled' class='label'>John Doe</div>"`. Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Or am I even approaching this at the right angle?

Thanks for any information!

Comment: try this `alert((this).find("div.label").innerHTML)`?

Comment: If you use jQuery it's cake. `$('div.label').text()` would get the contents of the div tag with the label class.

Comment: Your question really didn't have anything to do with PHP, i deleted the irrelevant info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting the innerHTML of the outer div, you want the innerHTML of the inner div.  In the DOM, the inner div is a child of the outer div, so get the outer div's first child and get the innerHTML of that.

Something like:

```
onclick=alert((this).childNodes[0].innerHTML)
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to read out the Full name from the `.label` DIV?
This should be what you want (plain JS, **no jQuery needed**):

```
<div class='row' onclick="alert((this).children[0].innerHTML)">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WuA9R/1/

Comment: This is probably the right solution. I'm assuming the user wants to get the info regardless of where on the row the user clicks.

Comment: you must agree that Jquery makes the beauty of JS ;)

Comment: @OfirBaruch yes, I personally love jQuery. BUT: sometimes jQuery is just not needed. it doesn't make sense to load the whole jQuery just for reading a `DIV`s content.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you are trying to do, but I believe that you are looking for the following (using jQuery):

```
<div class="row" onclick="alert( $(this).text() );">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$('.row').Click(function(){
 //var user_name = $(this).find("div.label").text();
 //or even better in case that the username is the only TEXT in the 'row' div:
 var user_name = $(this).text();


 //Do something with the user_name
 //Calling another function for example: getInformation(user_name);
});
</script>

<div class='row'>
    <div class='label'>
         John Doe
     </div>
</div>
<div class='listSeparator'></div>
```